# How can I use crop functionality in jet compose using registerForActivityResult?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, crop

I tried many solution but I want programmatically Answer.
Make sure I don't want to crop from compose in build function instead I want to select and crop image and then I want that URI.

Comment: There is no standard 'crop' intent on Android as per the [list of common intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common); you won't find anything that does this that works on even most devices.

Comment: then what is the solution in compose is I want to do this task any how?

Comment: https://thestreamliners.in/blog/using-intentlaunchers-in-compose/ Seems like this may work

Comment: That doesn't help if there is _literally no Intent you can fire to crop a picture_. You'll need to approach the problem entirely differently (i.e., include your own image cropping library, etc.)

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ohhh....  :-(